# map vs switch performance in go

Tags: performance, go, hashmap, switch-statement

Consider this benchmark, where we compare map access vs switch

```
var code = []int32{0, 10, 100, 100, 0, 10, 0, 10, 100, 14, 1000, 100, 1000, 0, 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10, 0, 1000, 12}
var mapCode = map[int32]int32{
    0:    1,
    10:   2,
    100:  3,
    1000: 4,
}

func BenchmarkMap(b *testing.B) {
    success := int32(0)
    fail := int32(0)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        // for each value in code array, do a specific action
        for _, v := range code {
            c, ok := mapCode[v]
            if !ok {
                fail++
            } else {
                success += c
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkSwitch(b *testing.B) {
    success := int32(0)
    fail := int32(0)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        // for each value in code array, do a specific action
        for _, v := range code {
            switch v {
            case 0:
                success++
            case 10:
                success += 2
            case 100:
                success += 3
            case 1000:
                success += 4
            default:
                fail++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the results:

```
BenchmarkMap-2           5000000           277 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSwitch-2       30000000            48.2 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

So using map seems to be way slower than switch.

I'm currently trying to optimize a function using a code similar to `BenchmarkMap()`, where the map access 
is the bottleneck, but I can't use switch as the map is dynamically generated when the program start (ie it
may change according to input arguments)

Is there a way to get similar performance as `switch x {}` with dynamically generated map ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not with a map, since [indexing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) maps are evaluated at runtime, and getting an element from a map involves more operations than just a single (slice-)indexing. Certain `switch`es (with `case` branches having constant expressions) can / may be optimized even at compile-time.

But map is not the only "dynamic" structure. For another one, there's [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). Slices can be indexed, just like maps.

Yes, a slice is a descriptor for a *contiguous segment* of an underlying array. Which means if you have an index like `1000`, the slice needs to have at least `1000+1 = 1001` elements.

So if you're willing to sacrifice some memory for the sake of performance and use a slice instead of a map, *you can even make your solution faster than the one using the `switch` statement*:

```
var sliceCode = []int32{
    0:    1,
    10:   2,
    100:  3,
    1000: 4,
}

func BenchmarkSlice(b *testing.B) {
    success := int32(0)
    fail := int32(0)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        // for each value in code array, do a specific action
        for _, v := range code {
            c := sliceCode[v]
            if c == 0 {
                fail++
            } else {
                success += c
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkMap-4          10000000               148 ns/op
BenchmarkSlice-4        100000000               17.6 ns/op
BenchmarkSwitch-4       50000000                31.0 ns/op
```

The slice solution in this concrete example **outperforms the `switch` solution by being twice as fast!**

**Notes:**

I mentioned above that if you have an index like `1000`, you need at least `1001` elements. This is partly true. For example if you'd have indices like `990..1000`, you could have a simple index transformation logic like `index - 990`, and then a slice with just 11 elements would be perfectly enough.

Also note that while indexing a map using the comma-ok idiom we were able to tell if the element was in the map. With slices we don't have that option. So we have to designate a value from the valid set of the element type, and use that as the "missing" signal. In the above example, `0` was perfect for us as that wasn't used (and all elements not explicitly listed are set to `0` by default). If in your example all valid `int32` values could be used, another option would be to use a wrapper or pointer type as the element type of the slice which could have a `nil` value, indicating that the element for the index is missing.

Comment: I'd also mention `sort.Search` which is a generalized tool to search in sorted slices using binary search algorythm.

Comment: @kostix Yes, but using binary search on a sorted slice will most likely perform worse than a map lookup.

Comment: Just implemented it in my function and got a nice 30% speedup, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7):

These results still hold five years later on go version 1.19 (after recent optimisations of the switch statement):

```
BenchmarkMap-10         14947908                76.78 ns/op
BenchmarkSwitch-10      49444435                23.01 ns/op
BenchmarkSlice-10       100000000               10.74 ns/op
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to get similar performance as switch x {} with dynamically generated map ?

No. I'm sorry.

Comment: @felix, …but you could look at [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to generate swaths of `switch` branches automatically -- given certain data.